# How to format cmd output and append it to reportlab PDF

Tags: python, formatting, subprocess, reportlab

I am trying to format my command prompt output, so that it looks the same when it is appended to Reportlab.

I am retrieving information about the PC, but it used to be written to a txt file. I know want it to write to a PDF file with a readable formatting.

This is how I setup the PDF file:

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("form_letter.pdf",
                                rightMargin=72, leftMargin=72,
                                topMargin=72, bottomMargin=18)
        Story = []
        logo = "python_logo.png"

        im = Image(logo, 2 * inch, 2 * inch)
        Story.append(im)
        Story.append(Spacer(1, 0.25 * inch))
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))
```

This is one of the outpouts I want to append to the PDF file, but this way it isn't readable:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["ipconfig"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding=sys_enc,
                                  startupinfo=startupinfo)
                ptext = f"<font size=12>{output.stdout.read()}</font>"
                Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Normal"]))
                Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
```

I want to get the output the same way it is when you type ipconfig in cmd for example. I hope someone is able to help. I am new to reportlab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to provide a runnable example. At least your imports should be listed, as they are quite a lot with reportlab as far as I remember, and you have even more. See also [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just figured out what I did wrong. I just Paragraph and needed to use Preformatted. That solved it for me and let me keep the cmd output formatting.